# How to find size of index in table-valued function

Tags: sql, sql-server

[In article about sys.indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-indexes-transact-sql) there is a phrase that this view

> Contains a row per index or heap of a tabular object, such as a table,
>   view, or **table-valued function**.

I was interested to find a size of such an index.

So I created function with index:

```
create function fIndexSize()
returns @res table
(
  object_id int          not null
, name      varchar(128) not null
, primary key (object_id)
)
as
begin
    insert into @res
    select object_id, name
    from sys.objects
    where object_id > 255
return
end
```

Here we can see the name of new index:

[image]

There is also a record in `sys.indexes`:

[image]

Usually I get sizes of indexes using this query:

```
select
      o.schema_id
    , o.object_id
    , o.name
    , o.type_desc
    , sum (a.total_pages) * 8.00 / 1024 / 1024 as TotalSpaceGB
from sys.objects o
inner join sys.indexes i on o.object_id = i.object_id
inner join sys.partitions p on i.object_id = p.object_id and i.index_id = p.index_id
inner join sys.allocation_units a on p.partition_id = a.container_id
where (o.name = 'fIndexSize' or i.name like 'PK__fIndexSi%')
group by o.schema_id, o.object_id, o.name, o.type_desc
```

But this time nothing was returned.

Can anyone give me advice how to find size of such an index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of a table-valued function is not stored in a permanent table in the database. It is generated on the fly during the query execution.

Yes, you have a row in `sys.indexes` which tells you index properties, like type (clustered or not), is_primary_key, is_unique, etc.

But, there are no corresponding rows in `sys.partitions` and in `sys.allocation_units`. That's why your query returns nothing. If you replace inner joins with left joins, you'd see one row with `NULL` as `TotalSpaceGB`.

So, documentation is correct. Documentation doesn't say that table-valued functions will have rows in `sys.allocation_units`.

Each invocation of the function may return different number of rows. This set of rows doesn't exist before the query runs and it doesn't exist after the query finishes.

Even during the function execution `sys.partitions` and `sys.allocation_units` are empty for this index (`PK__fIndexSi...`).

When I looked at the actual execution plan of the query

```
select * from fIndexSize()
```

I could see that optimiser creates a temp table behind the scenes. Well, it has to store the rows somewhere and they are stored in TempDB.

So, you should run your select from `sys.allocation_units` using `tempdb`.

At first I used SQL Sentry Plan Explorer to see the name of the temporary table:

[image: plan explorer]

Then I ran your query against TempDB:

[image: temp table sizes]

Comment: The multi-statement table-valued function is stored in sys.objects with type `TF`, but as you said, it is not materialized so has no space allocation. The query inner joins omit the object because it has no rows in sys.indexes, etc.

Comment: @DanGuzman, after a bit of experimentation I confirmed that the result set of a table-valued function is materialised in tempdb and it is possible to get its size via `sys.allocation_units`. I don't really know how to figure out the name of the temporary table in question on a busy server.

Comment: I didn't understand that the OP wanted the temporary space for each function invocation. That space per execution context rather than tied to the TVF itself.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can find the size of this index, but you should consider it's living only for a time of a batch and you should look for it in tempdb (as it is table variable):

```
    create function fIndexSize()
    returns @res table
    (
      object_id_xxxx int          not null
    , name      varchar(128) not null
    , primary key (object_id_xxxx)
    )
    as
    begin
        insert into @res
        select object_id, name
        from sys.objects
        where object_id > 255
    return
    end;
```

go

```
    select i.name,
           c.name,
           8 * SUM(au.used_pages) as size_kb
    from tempdb.sys.indexes i
         join tempdb.sys.columns c
            on i.object_id = c.object_id
         join tempdb.sys.partitions as p 
            on p.object_id = i.object_id and p.index_id = i.index_id
         join tempdb.sys.allocation_units as au 
            on au.container_id = p.partition_id        
    where c.name = 'object_id_xxxx' 
    group by  i.name,
              c.name
```

I left the column name here only to show that the index found is what we are looking for, and I chose the column name with xxxx for distinguish it well